# Embedded Kafka in micronaut app not finding beans

Tags: apache-kafka, micronaut

I'm using the embedded Kafka server in my test described here: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-kafka/latest/guide/#kafkaEmbedded. The problem is I'm getting this `io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanContextException: Error processing bean [Definition: org.app.messaging.TestConsumer] method definition [void receive(String msg)]: Failed to inject value for parameter [testService] of method [setTestService] of class: org.app.messaging.TestConsumer` when I run the test. Any ideas how to fix this?

Here's what the test looks like:

```
void "test run kafka embedded server"() {
    given:
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = ApplicationContext.run(
            Collections.singletonMap(
                    AbstractKafkaConfiguration.EMBEDDED, true
            )
    )

    when:
    AbstractKafkaConsumerConfiguration config = applicationContext.getBean(AbstractKafkaConsumerConfiguration)
    Properties props = config.getConfig()


    then:
    props[ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] == 9091


    when:
    KafkaEmbedded kafkaEmbedded = applicationContext.getBean(KafkaEmbedded)

    then:
    kafkaEmbedded.kafkaServer.isPresent()
    kafkaEmbedded.zkPort.isPresent()

    cleanup:
    applicationContext.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing a test anywhere other than the root package seem to be causing multiple "bean definition not found" issues. There's no `ComponentScan` support in the framework so the only thing that worked for me was to move the test file to the root package. There's some ideas here: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/511 if you're experiencing similar issues with a CLI app. However, it didn't work when using the embedded server and embedded kafka.